# Why is this thumbnail text so beautiful?

Tags: typography, font-identification, layout

[image]

[This image](https://i.ytimg.com/vi_webp/-woNlmVcdjc/mqdefault.webp) is the thumbnail for [this nerdwriter video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-woNlmVcdjc).

I'm about to begin a youtube series of my own, and I want my thumbnails to be that simple and beautiful, and I'm trying to understand how this design comes together. I'd like some help specifically understanding the design of the text.

Two things are eluding me:

- What is that font? (simple but important)
- What methodology could he be using to decide the different text sizes? I like way the text is justified and fits so naturally in a rectangle. Is there any obvious vertical rhythm thinking running underneath this?

Comment: On 'fits so cleanly in a square' (which is actually a rectangle): meh. The spacing is far too loose for my taste. The top line is sized and spaced out to match the width of the bottom line, that's really all there is to it.

Answer (score 4):

The design feature here is rectangles within rectangles.

The typeface is a condensed sans-serif with a heavy weight and in all caps, so each letter is very vertically rectangular, and each word is very horizontally rectangular. Then the text block is rectangular, and the text itself is justified so that the outside of the rectangle is defined. And of course it is basically cut out of the photo, which makes the shapes very clearly defined and easy to see.

So you have a little concert of rectangles. The human eye looks for patterns like this.

I don’t know the name of the typeface, but I don’t think it is important to copy that. Use any condensed sans-serif that you have available, in a heavy weight, set in all caps, and I think you will find that it works in the same way.

Answer (score -1):

These are four things we should consider while designing infographics.

1. Contrast
   We need to create enough contrast between objects to make them different from each other. There are several ways to create contrast.

   - Color: (which we can see in the above image. The text is white and the background is dark.)
   - Size: We can create contrast to make an object look bigger and the rest look smaller.
   - Shape: Asymmetrical objects always seem different than usual.
   - Weight: We can create contrast to make an object bold or elegant.
2. Alignment
   It gives strength to our design. All objects should be connected through an invisible line.
3. Composition
   Like symmetrical, center aligned, rule of third, negative space, etc.
4. Fonts
   Bold and sans serif fonts are best for infographics, but we can also use old types (Times New Roman) and serif fonts.

Comment: While these are very basic design concepts, I'm not sure your answer addresses the question directly. It also doesn't ask anything about infographics.

Comment: I agree with Luciano. -1.

Comment: Well design is universal. if are designing just thumbnails, or post for fb, ot just notify your user. all principals are working together, your work cant be dont after create contrast between fonts and background, you need to align those. and you need to select bold fonts for that.